# How to make a window in an activity?

Tags: android

I want to make a new window in an activity. like a popup window. I saw the source code of the Email application shipped with android OS and found this

```
import com.android.internal.policy.PolicyManager
Window w = PolicyManager.makeNewWindow(mContext);
```

But I can't find such a class in the SDK.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android.widget.PopupWindow might be what you're after. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Depending on what you're trying to do though, you may prefer using a dialog or an activity that isn't fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) or just use an `Activity` but with a dialog theme placing:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

in your `AndroidManifest` file.

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note. PopupWindow doesn't work well with Preferences screens. AlertDialog is not themable.